# fix multiple inheritance - recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I've been testing on how I could use dynamic class creation on doing things by configured layers. so I came across the option of using a class/layer multiple times. 
So, python does obviously not allow that, but I thought I fixed this with the `new` wrapper for `type`, that creates copies of baseclasses...

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.setrecursionlimit(25)           
>>> class C(object):
    def post(self):
        print("C", self.__class__)
        super().post()


>>> class B(object):
    def post(self):
        print("B", self.__class__)
        super().post()


>>> class A(object):
    def post(self):
        print("A", self.__class__)


>>> def new(name, bases, keys):
        r = []
        for e in bases:
            if not e in r:
                r.append(e)
            else:
                d = dict(e.__dict__)
                print(d)
                r.append(type(e.__name__, (e.__bases__), d))
        bases = tuple(r)
        return type(name, bases, keys)


>>> d2 = new("baum2", (C,B,C,B,A), {})
{'post': <function C.post at 0x02E8DB70>, '__module__': '__main__', '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'C' objects>, '__doc__': None, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'C' objects>}
{'post': <function B.post at 0x02E8DBB8>, '__module__': '__main__', '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'B' objects>, '__doc__': None, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'B' objects>}
>>> o = d2()
>>> o.post()
C <class '__main__.baum2'>
B <class '__main__.baum2'>
C <class '__main__.baum2'>
B <class '__main__.baum2'>
C <class '__main__.baum2'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#197>", line 1, in <module>
    o.post()
  File "<pyshell#185>", line 4, in post
    super().post()
  File "<pyshell#187>", line 4, in post
    super().post()
  File "<pyshell#185>", line 4, in post
    super().post()
  File "<pyshell#187>", line 4, in post
    super().post()
  File "<pyshell#185>", line 4, in post
    super().post()
  File "<pyshell#187>", line 3, in post
    print("B", self.__class__)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 1352, in write
    return self.shell.write(s, self.tags)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

So why do I get a recursion on `super()`?
I'd be happy if there was a way to do explicit baseclass duplicates...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the `super()` in the copied classes still create proxy objects for the original class, but I can't think of a way to prove it...

Comment: i tested a copy_func i found in another question to "recreate" the methods in `d` to test that. same behavior. but i don't know how far this could really have had any effect...

Comment: You can kind of see that it's true if you remove the `r.append(e)` bit and _always_ create a copy of each base class.

Comment: I tested it. The suggested code executes only until the first `super()` call and raises TypeError.
But that doesn't give any clue on fixing it, does it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the behaviour of `super()`. Even though you create copies of the base classes, the `super()` calls still behave as though they were inside the original class.

The following code shows that this is true:

```
class A:
    def p(self):
        print(super())

A2= type('A2', A.__bases__, A.__dict__.copy())

class B(A2,A): pass #make sure to inherit from A2 first

A().p() # output: <super: <class 'A'>, <A object>>
B().p() # output: <super: <class 'A'>, <B object>>
```

As we can see, `super()` still creates a proxy object for the original class `A`.

Knowing this, it's easy to understand where the infinite recursion happens: Since the MRO of your child class is `(C, B, C (copied), B (copied), A)`, the `super()` in `B` passes the baton to the copied `C`, which then passes it back to `B`, and so on.

---

As for "fixing" this problem... I think you neither can, nor should. Whatever you were trying to achieve with this form of multiple inheritance, there's almost certainly a better way to do it.

Comment: I'm aware I shouldn't. But i want it :D I think it would get solved by re-executing the entire class body. But i don't see such option. classes do not expose their __code__ by default.

Comment: Most shortest approach would be to recieve the baseclass from a class-generating-function. I guess this will do it for now.